# How to number and reference to "definitions" in latex

Tags: cross-referencing

I want the following format in LaTeX:

```
Definition 1 [apple]:
apple is a fruit.

Definition 2 [cat]:
cat is a fluffy animal. 
.
.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  How are you constructing these "definitions"; are "theorems" or "list items"?  Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to show us your set-up.

Answer (score 6):

Without using any packages you could use inbuilt theorem environment

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}

%use next two lines instead for non-italic alternative
%\newtheorem{preremark}{Definition}
%\newenvironment{mydef}{\begin{preremark}\upshape}{\end{preremark}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{mydef}\label{def:def444}
Here is a new definition
\end{mydef}

\begin{mydef}[Somebody]\label{def:def555}
Here is another new definition
\end{mydef}

That was Definition~\ref{def:def444} and Definition~\ref{def:def555}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe with `amsthm` and `\theoremstyle{definition}` to have the body text in upright shape.

Comment: @egreg Actually in the interests of minimalism you don't need amsthm to make it upright -- just an extra line or two of code. Modified my MWE to add that as a commented option

Comment: With the `preremark` strategy, you lose the optional argument.

Comment: Ah, indeed - noted

Answer (score 3):

On a even lower level:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{definition}

\newcommand{\definition}[2]% #1 = name, #2 = definition
{\refstepcounter{definition}%
\par\noindent Definition \thedefinition\ [#1]:\newline #2\medskip\par}

\begin{document}
\definition{apple}{apple is a fruit.}\label{test1}
\definition{cat}{cat is a fluffy animal.}\label{test2}

 That was Definition \ref{test1} and Definition \ref{test2}.
\end{document}
```

[image: counter and command]